# Angular Cannot read property 'signup' of undefined post call using web API

Tags: angular

I am getting the below error. when i click signup button. calling Web API

```
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'signup' of undefined
    at SignUpComponent.push.Qv8w.SignUpComponent.signup (sign-up.component.ts:107)
    at SignUpComponent_Template_button_click_46_listener (sign-up.component.html:135)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15220)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15255)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dom_renderer.ts:66)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28522)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:433)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:205)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:516)**
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiProvider } from '../../../providers/api';

import { CoreConfigService } from '@core/services/config.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

 // Public
 public fullnameVar;
 public phonenumberVar;
 public emailVar;
 public passwordVar;
 public coreConfig: any;
 public passwordTextType: boolean;
//  private http: HttpClient;
 

 // Private
 private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;

 /**
  * Constructor
  *
  * @param {CoreConfigService} _coreConfigService
  */
 constructor(private _coreConfigService: CoreConfigService,
  private api: ApiProvider) {
   this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();

   // Configure the layout
   this._coreConfigService.config = {
     layout: {
       navbar: {
         hidden: true
       },
       menu: {
         hidden: true
       },
       footer: {
         hidden: true
       },
       customizer: false,
       enableLocalStorage: false
     }
   };
 }

 /**
  * Toggle password
  */
 togglePasswordTextType() {
   this.passwordTextType = !this.passwordTextType;
 }

 // Lifecycle Hooks
 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 /**
  * On init
  */
 ngOnInit(): void {
   // Subscribe to config changes
   this._coreConfigService.config.pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)).subscribe(config => {
     this.coreConfig = config;
   });
 }

 /**
  * On destroy
  */
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
   // Unsubscribe from all subscriptions
   this._unsubscribeAll.next();
   this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
 }


 /**
  * Sign Up Function call code
  */
  signup() {
    var checkError ="false";
    debugger;
    if (this.fullnameVar == undefined || this.passwordVar ==undefined || this.phonenumberVar ==undefined || this.emailVar ==undefined) {
      checkError ="true";
    } 
    else {
     // this.api.startLoading();
     if(checkError =="false")
     {
        let data = {
          "FullName": this.fullnameVar,
          "PhoneNumber": this.phonenumberVar,
          "Password": this.passwordVar,
          "EmailID": this.emailVar,
        }
        console.log("signup:" , data);
        this.api.signup(data).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
     }, error => console.error(error));
     }
      
    }

  }
}
```

Html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" tabindex="5" rippleEffect (click)="signup()">Sign up</button>
```

Service:

```
     @Injectable()
    export class ApiProvider {
    
      public base_url: any = 'http://localhost:57716/';
      // public tenantId: any = 'c9d4c053-49b6-410c-bc78-2d54a9991870/';
      // public branchId: any = '3D490A70-94CE-4D15-9494-5248280C2CE5/';
      // public departmentId: any = '2bcf5f08-a465-4ee6-a4ff-02855e966fce';
    
      loading: any;
    
      constructor(public http: HttpClient 
        ) {
        console.log('Hello ApiProvider Provider');
      }

  signup(data) {

    return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'api/values', data);

  }
```

Comment: I can't see where you injected the service in your component. It seems you didn't. Please inject the service with a constructor.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm already present in the code. but not working.

Comment: use service instead of provider

Comment: @IvinRaj Why you also have ApiProvider in constructor of ApiProvider?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm removed same problem

Comment: @IvinRaj Could you also include the imports? Maybe you have some circular references. Could you additionally show the module where you provided the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject service in constructor of SignUpComponent like below :

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

 public fullnameVar;
 public phonenumberVar;
 public emailVar;
 public passwordVar;
 public coreConfig: any;
 public passwordTextType: boolean;
 // REMOVE ApiProvider FROM HERE

constructor(
   private api: ApiProvider
){
}
```

Comment: You have to add it in your SignUpComponent. Not in the service file

Comment: Added the same code but it is not working.,

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link?

Comment: Working fine. thaNKS